# How to solve " Operation error unable to open database file"?

Tags: python, django, apache, sqlite, bitnami

I am using bitnami for hosting my django web app which uses apache.
Every time I login into my django admin panel it shows

```
Django Version: 1.11
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
unable to open database file
Exception Location: /opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py in execute, line 328
```

I cant handle anything which involved my db.sqlite3.
My db.sqlite3 permissions are 775 with group=daemon and owner= bitnami.

This is my settings.py snippet

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use sqlite; use a proper database (Postgres or MySQL).

Comment: Hi, Bitnami Engineer here. Could you please let us know more information about your deployment? Is it a fresh deployment or did you modify any configuration or deployed a custom Django application on top of it?

Comment: Well I solved this by setting permission to my db.sqlite3 777.

Comment: But there is some issue with bitnami ubuntu cloud, may be i am wrong. Everytime I install some django-library using pip. I cant use it my code. They say I cant import it, there is some serious permission issue with all your stuffs. Can you help me with that?